# How can I set an auto respond email based on drop-down?

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

We have a freeform form on a site's contact page. In that form there's a dynamic recipient drop-down field for Subject which emails a different person on the team depending on the subject (functionality built into freeform). We also need to send a auto response to the sender but only if they select a specific option for subject. Any ideas how to go about this? Example:

- "Interested in working together" - emails person 1
- "Business proposal" - emails person 2
- "Careers enquiry" - emails person 1 AND sends an email to the person who submitted the form